# Android SDK on docker

Tags: android, docker, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

Im trying to run android emulator on docker but I get the following error, I have done some research but none of the answers helped me in achieving my goal, here is the error that I get and my docker file, I have tried armeabi and system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86  and both did not work.

```
# emulator -avd device
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Warning: could not connect to display  ((null):0, (null))


emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Info: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/opt/android-sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins" even though it was found. ((null):0, (null))


Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
 ((null):0, (null))
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
 ((null):0, (null))


Aborted
```

Im doing the same steps on my MAC and it's working fine, here is my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libncurses5:i386 libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1 zlib1g:i386 && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git wget unzip && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends qt5-default

ARG GRADLE_VERSION=5.2.1
ARG GRADLE_DIST=bin
RUN cd /opt && \
    wget -q https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}-${GRADLE_DIST}.zip && \
    unzip gradle*.zip && \
    ls -d */ | sed 's/\/*$//g' | xargs -I{} mv {} gradle && \
    rm gradle*.zip

# download and install Android SDK
# https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads
ARG ANDROID_SDK_VERSION=4333796
ENV ANDROID_HOME /opt/android-sdk
RUN mkdir -p ${ANDROID_HOME} && cd ${ANDROID_HOME} && \
    wget -q https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-${ANDROID_SDK_VERSION}.zip && \
    unzip *tools*linux*.zip && \
    rm *tools*linux*.zip
# set the environment variables
ENV APK_SIGNER=/opt/android-sdk/build-tools/29.0.2/
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT /opt/android-sdk
ENV GRADLE_HOME /opt/gradle
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin/apksigner:${APK_SIGNER}
ENV _JAVA_OPTIONS -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap
# WORKAROUND: for issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137213
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64:${ANDROID_HOME}/emulator/lib64/qt/lib


# accept the license agreements of the SDK components
ADD docker/license_accepter.sh /opt/
RUN chmod +x /opt/license_accepter.sh && /opt/license_accepter.sh $ANDROID_HOME

# setup adb server
EXPOSE 5037

# install and configure SSH server
EXPOSE 22
ADD docker/sshd-banner /etc/ssh/
ADD docker/authorized_keys /tmp/
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server supervisor locales && \
    mkdir -p /var/run/sshd /var/log/supervisord && \
    locale-gen en en_US en_US.UTF-8 && \
    apt-get remove -y locales && apt-get autoremove -y && \
    FILE_SSHD_CONFIG="/etc/ssh/sshd_config" && \
    echo "\nBanner /etc/ssh/sshd-banner" >> $FILE_SSHD_CONFIG && \
    echo "\nPermitUserEnvironment=yes" >> $FILE_SSHD_CONFIG && \
    ssh-keygen -q -N "" -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa && \
    FILE_SSH_ENV="/root/.ssh/environment" && \
    touch $FILE_SSH_ENV && chmod 600 $FILE_SSH_ENV && \
    printenv | grep "JAVA_HOME\|GRADLE_HOME\|ANDROID_HOME\|LD_LIBRARY_PATH\|PATH" >> $FILE_SSH_ENV && \
    FILE_AUTH_KEYS="/root/.ssh/authorized_keys" && \
    touch $FILE_AUTH_KEYS && chmod 600 $FILE_AUTH_KEYS && \
    for file in /tmp/*.pub; \
    do if [ -f "$file" ]; then echo "\n" >> $FILE_AUTH_KEYS && cat $file >> $FILE_AUTH_KEYS && echo "\n" >> $FILE_AUTH_KEYS; fi; \
    done && \
    (rm /tmp/*.pub 2> /dev/null || true)

ADD docker/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
ADD docker/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
ADD docker/android.keystore /Android-APK/
ADD app/build/outputs/apk/release/ /Android-APK/
RUN sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29" "build-tools;29.0.2" "add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-24"

RUN apksigner sign --ks /Android-APK/android.keystore --ks-pass pass:android --key-pass pass:android --in /Android-APK/app-release-unsigned.apk --out /Android-APK/signed-app.apk
RUN zipalign -f 4 /Android-APK/signed-app.apk /Android-APK/aligned-app.apk
#RUN sdkmanager "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"
#RUN adb install /Android-APK/aligned-app.apk

#RUN sdkmanager "system-images;android-25;google_apis;arm64-v8a"
#RUN avdmanager create avd --force --name "device" --abi "arm64-v8a" --package 'system-images;android-25;google_apis;arm64-v8a' --device "Nexus 10"
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: @jamesNewbould, to be honest, I gave up, but it's doable somehow. let me know if you figure it out

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and it ended up being that our script was running the incorrect version of the emulator (26, which doesn't have good support for headless yet)

It should be running

```
$ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator -avd avd-name -no-skin -no-audio -no-window
```

and not the emulator in the tools folder.

Check the version of the emulator by just running the executable. My output (that works) is

```
emulator: Android emulator version 30.4.5.0 (build_id 7140946) (CL:N/A)
emulator: ERROR: No AVD specified. Use '@foo' or '-avd foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

first run

```
xhost +
```

then run your docker container like this

```
docker run -i -t --net=host --privileged --env="DISPLAY" \
-v $HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw \
-v ~/disk1/android_docker:/home/android \
android-image /bin/bash
```

then you can run

```
emulator
```